# Run the makefile

Tags: makefile, open-source, contiki

I am trying to run https://github.com/pavanpongle/IoT-Wormhole-IDS. After following `README.md` and `Instructions to run`, I understood that I need to use the `Makefile`. I have properly indented the file which now looks as below:

```
DEFINES+=PROJECT_CONF_H=\"project-conf.h\"
all:$(CONTIKI_PROJECT)

CONTIKI=../..

WITH_UIP6=1
UIP_CONF_IPV6=1

CFLAGS+= -DUIP_CONF_IPV6_RPL -DUIP_CONF_IPV6 -DWITH_UIP6
LDLIBS=-lm
ifdef PERIOD
CFLAGS=-DPERIOD=$(PERIOD)
endif

include $(CONTIKI)/Makefile.include
```

I have given execute permissions to the Makefile. After running `make`, the following message is displayed.

`make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.`

If `CONTIKI_PROJECT` should be assigned some value before `all:`, then what should it be?

I am not able to understand if I am missing anything from contiki point of view or it is just to do something with the Makefile.

How do I make this project work?

Comment: Read the GNU make manual for the basics: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONTIKI_PROJECT` should refer to the name of your application, which is the same as the name of main `.c` file with the application's source code.

Here is the `hello-world` [example Makefile](https://github.com/pavanpongle/IoT-Wormhole-IDS/blob/master/examples/hello-world/Makefile) from the project you linked to:

```
CONTIKI_PROJECT = hello-world
all: $(CONTIKI_PROJECT)

CONTIKI = ../..
include $(CONTIKI)/Makefile.include
```

Comment: Thanks! After I run hello-world in IoT-Wormhole-IDS using http://anrg.usc.edu/contiki/index.php/Hello_World, I am getting No such file or directory "powertrace.h".


I have verified that file does exist. I studied http://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists and installed required packages. But still `powertrace.h: No such file or directory`.


I could successfully run hello-world in https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki but not for IoT-Wormhole-IDS as powertrace.h (../apps/powertrace) is its dependency. 


Any Idea on how do I proceed?

Comment: That's almost a separate question. Add the line `APPS += powertrace` to the Makefile for that. Create a new question if you need more info.